# get dbpedia type/category for any word

Tags: dbpedia

I am trying to get type/category to which the word belongs to like if its basketball then its under the category sports and if its tea then beverage is the category.

I tried :

```
select * where {basketball} LIMIT 100
```

and

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbres: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

select ? {
    a owl:basketball .
}
limit 10
```

also

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbres: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT ?y WHERE {
 ?y dbpedia-owl:binomialAuthority dbres:basketball.
 }

limit 10
```

but there is a query error especially if I dont know the property of the word typed.How can I get the name of the category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you can query rdf:type of basketball.

```
PREFIX dbres: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
select ?o where {dbres:Basketball rdf:type ?o} LIMIT 10
```

[Demo](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20dbres%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdf%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0Aselect%20%3Fo%20where%20%7Bdbres%3ABasketball%20rdf%3Atype%20%3Fo%7D%20LIMIT%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Awesome.Thanks +1 .Also How can I make http/json call ?

Comment: You can get json with simple request like http://dbpedia.org/data/Basketball.json

Comment: But I get a long list not the type like just sport.

Comment: Change the above query result format to json. For example: http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+dbres%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+rdf%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0Aselect+%3Fo+where+%7Bdbres%3ABasketball+rdf%3Atype+%3Fo%7D+LIMIT+10&format=json